# Getting the point of a rectangle's corners on the screen while rotating

Tags: java, swing, graphics, shapes

I am creating a basic 2D game and I am currently trying to get the x and y (Point) of all of the rectangle's corners while I rotate the rectangle.

```
private static Graphics2D drawRect(Graphics2D g)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(350,350,75,75);
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotation), rect.getX() + rect.width/2, rect.getY() + rect.height/2);
    AffineTransform old = g.getTransform();
    g.transform(transform);

    g.fill(rect);
    if(z >= 1000)
    {
        // here I am asking it to print out the x,y of the point at the top left of the rectangle
        System.out.println(rect.getX() + " : " + rect.getY() + " : " + rotation);
        z = 0;
    }
    g.setTransform(old);
    z++;
    return g;
}
```

When I run this it starts at 350, 350 as shown and will rotate in either direction depending on how I increment it.  It rotates through graphics correctly.  But when I want to print the point of the x,y of the original top left point it always returns with 350, 350.  If I rotate it 45 degrees in the positive direction it would return 350, 350.  I have made a click function so I can click on the screen and it properly returns the x and y of the click spot.  When I click on the original top left corner of the rectangle it returns 311,334. This is the return I am looking for when calculating the top left corner x,y.
Visual here:

[picture of before rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3G62.png)

[picture of after rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDXQ7.png)

Comment: There's probably a really neat way to do this, but based on the what (little) I know, I know I can calculate the angle between two points, so given the center point of the rectangle and the top/left corner of the rectangle, I can calculate the angle, this represents an offset.  I know I can calculate the point on a circle, given an angle and a radius.  So, assuming that the radius is is the longest length of the rectangle, plus your inputted angle and the offset angle, you should be able to calculate the new x/y position of the top/left corner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying your transform on the graphics object. Therefore, the rectangle object itself is not modified.

`AffineTransform` has two methods you can make use of. `createTransformedShape` which returns a new shape that is transformed accordingly or `transform(Point2D ptSrc, Point2D ptDst)` which will transform the point ptSrc and save the transformed point in ptDst:

```
Point rotatedPoint = new Point();
transform.transform(new Point(rect.x, rect.y), rotatedPoint);
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but ;), `Rectangle#getX/Y` returns a `Double` and `Point` expects an `int`, you can use `Point2D.Double` (which is probably preferable) or `Rectangle#x/y`, but, +1 for teaching me something new and neat ;)

Comment: Thanks man, works like a charm and returns the correct x,y point. <3